# convergence of continuous mapped RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

This is an extension of the result in my textbook, I'm wondering if it's true and if there are any references to it's proof.

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $g :
\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be continuous at $\bigcup_{n =
1}^{\infty} \text{Img} (X_n)$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$:

- if $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ then $g (X_n) \xrightarrow{a.s.} g (X)$
- if $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ then $g (X_n) \xrightarrow{P} g (X)$
- if $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ then $g (X_n) \xrightarrow{d} g (X)$

The textbook result has $g$ continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, continuity on $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{Img}(X_n)$ is not enough.

**(Counter)Example:** Consider $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1])$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure, $$g(x) := 1_{\{0\}}(x)$$ and $$X_n := \frac{1}{n}.$$ Then $X_n \to X := 0$ almost surely, $g$ is continuous on $(0,\infty) \supseteq \bigcup_n \text{Img}(X_n)$, but $g(X_n)=0$ does not converge to $g(X)=1$ almost surely. This example also shows that the claim does not hold true if we replace "convergence almost surely" by "convergence in probability" or "convergence in distribution".